# How to setup Leverage Browsing cache and Gzip Compression in Laravel project

Tags: laravel-5, gzip, browser-cache

I'm trying to enable **Gzip Compression and leverage Browser cache in Laravel** for website optimization.
I don't have an idea how to enable them in Laravel.

Any help/suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: This is a server configuration, not Laravel related. You need to configure your apache or nginx.

Comment: @thefallen thanks for the reply. But I  thought I need to update in .htaccess file.

Comment: It could be done from htaccess, but you also need to enable a module for your apache. There is plenty information on the web.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Enable gzip:**

There are different methods of setting up gzip compression depending on whether or not you've got an IIS or Apache server (or something else entirely).

For Apache:
You will need to add the following lines to your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

After you've saved your .htaccess file, test your site again in [Google Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) or [Gtmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/)  to make sure it has been properly compressed.

**Enable leverage browser caching:**

add the following code again to your .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On

  # Images
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

  # Video
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType video/mpeg "access plus 1 year"

  # CSS, JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"

  # Others
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

**Be careful**
You want to be careful when enabling browser caching as if you set the parameters too long on certain files, users might not be getting the fresh version of your website after updates.

This is particularly relevant if you are working with a designer to make changes to your website – they might have made the changes but you can't see them yet because the elements that have been changed are cached on your browser.

Comment: That's why developers would use a parameter on the link or script tags to force a new request

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + R will do a hard reload and refetch updated resources. I use that